# How to save form data in multiple page with just one form

Tags: php, html

I have an expert system in php, but it cannot show the option who already answered by user, it just show the result, I think the problem is that the system uses multiple page, if the user answers the first option, the next option shall open in different page, until the result come out, but the option built by one form.

Please show me the way to enable the option user picked show with the result in my expert system.

Comment: Can you please share some code from your expert system?

Comment: A link to the actual system would be good too, or some screen image(s) of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this before, where a user could click through 3 pages, and go backward and forward, and we didn't want to lose progress.

My solution was to pass the entire form from page to page, repopulate the answers with what was just posted, and simply keep all those values in hidden elements on the form.

In other words, the entire form is hidden elements.  The part the user edits and sees may only be a few fields at any time, but ALL the actual information is stored in hidden fields.